# box whisker plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got a boxplot graph like this:
[image]

my dataset is like this (the number below is just an example, not the real one I used):

```
dataset = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]........]
```

The "dataset" list consists of 12 items, each one has ten float numbers in it.

Now I want to change the x axis, for example, the first list in the dataset is calculated when prameter `a=50`, the second list is calculated when a = 100, etc. I want to display the boxes with `a` value as x axis instead of 1,2,3,4,5,...like now

I have a list of a value:

```
a = [50, 100, 200, 350, 480.......]
```

code to create the graph:

```
dataset = [...] (the structure is showed above)
ax.boxplot(dataset)
```

Comment: Show the *code* you used to create it

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`positions`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) keyword argument:

```
ax.boxplot(dataset, positions=a)
```